# Implementing Enhanced Ecommerce (UA) using DTM

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics, universal-analytics

We are going to kick start the implementation of Enhanced Ecommerce tracking in Universal Analytics, but using Adobe's tag manager i.e. DTM.

Google Universal Analytics page code is already present on the site (in tradition way, not with the help of any tag management solution) and since we can leverage DTM to add to our existing implementation, rather than starting from scratch, we are using it.

Has anyone implemented this before?

Comment: The only actual question I see here is asking if anybody has implemented GA through DTM.  The answer to that is "Yes, I have." And I'm sure lots of other people have, as well. Do you have anything more specific to ask? Trouble implementing something in particular?

Comment: We have just started implementing it, and I will get back here in case I am stuck.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I am getting this error, 
`SATELLITE: GAU: Page code not loaded(suppressed).` on the page  load. 

I have a added a new tool (Google Universal Analytics) in the existing web property and added Production and Staging Account ID (the same Account ID which is present in the page code), since Google Universal Analytics is already implemented. 

Any idea, what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

> @CrayonViolent I am getting this error, `SATELLITE: GAU: Page code not
>   loaded(suppressed).` on the page load. I have a added a new tool
>   (Google Universal Analytics) in the existing web property and added
>   Production and Staging Account ID (the same Account ID which is
>   present in the page code), since Google Universal Analytics is already
>   implemented. Any idea, what is going wrong here ?

You are getting this message because you have enabled (checked) the **Google Universal Analytics page code is already present** setting. This option is misleading and does not work as advertised.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088109/adobe-dynamic-tag-management-dtm-page-load-rules-not-being-captured/30088975#30088975) for details about what that setting really does in practice (read the comments too). The post is for the Adobe Analytics tool but it's the same principle for GA/UA tool setting. But the long story short is that setting isn't *really* for building on an existing implementation; it's for helping you get the ball rolling for migration.